# Return max value in a column with peewee

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlite, peewee

I have a table called jobs with a column called job_num.
How do i return the maximum value of the integers in that column?

I have tried

```
result = Job.select(max(Job.job_num))
```

I have also tried a few different combinations such as

```
result = Job.select(Job.job_num).max()
```

I have also checked the peewee docs.
Can anyone help please.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use "fn.MAX" to apply the SQL MAX function. The "scalar()" method returns a single, scalar result value:

```
result = Job.select(fn.MAX(Job.job_num)).scalar()
```